# how to fetch id from http url in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my code i want to make when i select on radio button then click submit button then url is open this is fine right now.

But i want to make when i select on radio button and click on submit button then url is open with id fetch

and id is fetched in api on the basis of row select.

my full code is here plz check https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-forked-hvisq?file=/index.js

i want to make when i select row and click on submit button then this type url is open
http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/space%20station.png/id/1 like that on another row when i select row and click on button then this type url is open http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/space%20station.png/id/2.

but right now its simply url open without fetch id on the basis of select http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/space%20station.png.

How can we do that.any idea on that

my code https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-forked-hvisq?file=/index.js

```
 handleClick = () => {
    console.log(this.state.selectedId);
    const apiUrl = "https://mocki.io/v1/b512f8b8-64ab-46e4-9e0c-9db538a0ad9e";
    if (this.state.selectedId) {
      console.log(this.state.selectedId);
      fetch(apiUrl)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          this.setState({ data: data });
          console.log("This is your data", data);
          switch (this.state.selectedId) {
            case "1":
              window.open(
                "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/double_ship.png",
                "_blank"
              );
              break;
            case "2":
              window.open(
                "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/double_ship.png",
                "_blank"
              );
              break;
            default:
              break;
          }
        });
    } else {
      alert("Data not fetched!");
    }
  };
```

anybody help me out its very thankful.

Comment: anybody plz help me out. its very thankful. i m stuck on that

Comment: What do you mean by `url is open with id fetch`?

Comment: @ShivamJha as u can see my code https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-forked-hvisq?file=/index.js when i select row and click on submit button the url is opened ok but i wnat to make url with id http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/space%20station.png/id/1  like that

Comment: @ShivamJha hope u getting my point.and is it possible to do that??

Comment: Code should be in the question itself as a [mcve]. Links can go stale over time making the question useless for future visitors.

Comment: i have edited my question above

Comment: @rennukumari so `data` is an array of objects, You want to pick the `url` of the object in the `data` array where the `id` matches `this.state.selectedId`.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically just had to add the `"/id/" + this.state.selectedId` part to your url and that's it.

Is this what you wanted ?

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-forked-wkrjw?file=/index.js

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's very straightforward unless I'm misinterpreting the question.

Here is the fork and I did the change on line 48 and 54 in the window.open function.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-forked-30glc

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, `data` is an array of objects which looks like,

```js
{
  id: number,
  url: string
}
```

You want to pick the `url` of the object in the `data` array where the `id` matches `this.state.selectedId`.

You can replace your `switch` statement with the following,

```js
window.open(data.find((d) => d.id === Number(this.state.selectedId)).url);
```

Forked example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-forked-5mr12?file=/index.js